# Error:(17, 19) String types not allowed (at 'font' with value 'font_regular.ttf')

Tags: android, android-fonts

I used Android studio 2.3 version before and now updated to 3.0 stable version and target version 25 to 26. I kept all my customs fonts `Assets` folder

I am using it in my xml like:

```
app:font="font_regular.ttf"
```

using

> compileSdkVersion 26
>
> buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
>
> minSdkVersion 16
>
> targetSdkVersion 26
>
> renderscriptTargetApi 26

When I am trying to use my custom fonts which are in Assets folder it's was worked fine before 3.0 but now it's showing error like:

> Error:(17, 19) String types not allowed (at 'font' with value 'font_regular.ttf').

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Hey got quick solution by referencing from developer [Doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html)

> Android 8.0 (API level 26) introduces a new feature, Fonts in XML, which lets you use fonts as resources. You can add the font file in the res/font/ folder to bundle fonts as resources. These fonts are compiled in your R file and are automatically available in Android Studio. You can access the font resources with the help of a new resource type, font. For example, to access a font resource, use @font/myfont, or R.font.myfont.

So I moved all my fons in to `font` folder inside the `res`

Now am using it like:

```
app:font="@font/font_regular"
```